# Resources for WPF DataGrid Add, Update and Delete using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am looking for a sample code/Article which would demonstrate WPF DataGrid in action with MVVM pattern to add, updated and delete record from database.

I have a specific requirement for allowing user to insert new record using DataGrid not a new child form.

If anyone can recommend good resource or provide a sample for that particular task it would be great help for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here on CodeProject is an article about WPF DataGrid + MVVM pattern:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MVVM_DataGrid.aspx

Comment: The project you linked to doesn't do add or update, and only does delete by using a delete button, not with the DataGrid's delete row.  I too, am finding it extremely frustrating trying to find real world examples on how to use MVVM for CRUD operations using a DataGrid!  I'm starting to think that MVVM is a myth.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any good articles on the subject, but I don't see the problem; as long as you bind to an ObservableCollection or ListCollectionView containing objects whose class has a default constructor (I don't think there are other restrictions), the DataGrid will handle things pretty well. The collection you bind to must have some way of adding new items, which is why you need to bind to an ICollection or IEditableCollectionView - the latter is preferred, as it has specific options for controlling the creation of items - see `AddNew`, `CanAddNew` etc, which the DataGrid works well with.

Comment: in my case the problem is to determine which row is changed/deleted

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. The way new items work with the DataGrid is that there's a NewItemPlaceholder (which by default has the same structure as any other datagrid row), which when focused creates a new temporary data item, and when commited (losing focus, enter key etc) inserts that item in the collection. IIRC everything is hardcoded a lot, so maybe you can't change as much as you want, but you should try it, it was pretty much always enough for me.

Comment: lets forget the new items , lets talk about existing items , how can I delete a row , delete means to delete it from the grid and from the database as well, here is my problem

Comment: It depends on the data access technology you use, but here's a simple idea: assuming you use objects (as opposed to DataTables) and you have an ObservableCollection filled with items loaded from the database, hook up a handler to the collection's CollectionChanged event. In the handler check the eventargs to see what kind of operation it was; if an item was removed, you have the item in the eventargs' OldItems list; take the (only) object in that list, convert it to your specific type and delete it from the database like you would do normally from code.

Comment: gonna give it a try , although I've heared that using EventArgs is a bad MVVM practice , thanks anyway

Comment: That probably refers to using events exposed by controls, although even that is acceptable (with some abstraction) as far as I'm concerned - of course you can abstract that away too and hook those events to ICommands, but with some events it may be impractical. People usually attach way too much to MVVM; it's just a set of guidelines. The events I'm talking about all happen inside the ViewModel, so the method doesn't go against MVVM in the slightest.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**:Pasted the part, which fits your question.
Full article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples

This example demonstrates how to use a DataGrid to perform CRUD operations via binding where the database integration is decoupled via a Data Access Layer (DAL).

The Architecture

This example is a simple CRUD application which allows the user to edit items in the Customers table of the Northwind database. The example has a Data Access Layer, which exposes Find/ Delete/Update methods that operate on simple data objects, and a Presentation Layer that adapts these objects in such a way that they can be bound effectively by the WPF Framework. Because we are only performing CRUD functions, I have not added a Business Logic Layer (BLL); if you are a purist, you could add a pass-through BLL; however, I feel it would add little to this example.

The key classes within this architecture are shown below:

The Data Access Layer exposes an interface for managing the lifecycle of the Customer Data Objects. The class which implements this interface uses a typed DataSet as a database integration layer; however, this is hidden from the clients of the DAL. The presence of this layer means that we are not directly coupled to the database schema or the generated dataset schema, i.e., we can change our schema, yet still provide the interface given below to our clients:

```
public interface ICustomerDataAccessLayer
{
    /// Return all the persistent customers
    List<CustomerDataObject> GetCustomers();

    /// Updates or adds the given customer
    void UpdateCustomer(CustomerDataObject customer);

    /// Delete the given customer
    void DeleteCustomer(CustomerDataObject customer);
}
public class CustomerDataObject
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public string ContactName { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, there are no UI framework specific interfaces or classes (such as ObservableCollection) exposed by the DAL. The problem here is how to bind the customers returned by ICustomerDataAccess.GetCustomers to our DataGrid and ensure that changes are synchronised with the database.

We could bind the DataGrid directly to our customer collection, List; however, we need to ensure that the UpdateCustomer and DeleteCustomer methods on our DAL interface are invoked at the appropriate points in time. One approach that we might take is to handle the events / commands exposed by the DataGrid in order to determine what action it has just performed or intends to perform on the bound customer collection. However, in doing so, we would be writing integration code that is specific to the DataGrid. What if we wanted to change the UI to present a ListView and a number of TextBoxes (details view)? We would have to re-write this logic. Also, none of the DataGrid events quite fit what we want. There are "Ending" events, but no "Ended" events; therefore, the data visible to event handlers is not in its committed state. A better approach would be if we could adapt our collection of Customer objects in such a way that they could be bound to any suitable WPF UI control, with add/edit/remove operations synchronised with the database via our DAL.
Handling Delete Operations

The ObservableCollection class is a good candidate for our data binding needs. It exposes a CollectionChanged event which is fired whenever items are added or removed from the collection. If we copy our customer data into an ObservableCollection and bind this to the DataGrid, we can handle the CollectionChanged event and perform the required operation on the DAL. The following code snippet shows how the CustomerObjectDataProvider (which is defined as an ObjectDataProvider in the XAML) constructs an ObservableCollection of CustomerUIObjects. These UI objects simply wrap their data object counterparts in order to expose the same properties.

```
public CustomerObjectDataProvider()
{
    dataAccessLayer = new CustomerDataAccessLayer();
}

public CustomerUIObjects GetCustomers()
{
    // populate our list of customers from the data access layer
    CustomerUIObjects customers = new CustomerUIObjects();

    List<CustomerDataObject> customerDataObjects = dataAccessLayer.GetCustomers();
    foreach (CustomerDataObject customerDataObject in customerDataObjects)
    {
        // create a business object from each data object
        customers.Add(new CustomerUIObject(customerDataObject));
    }

    customers.CollectionChanged += new
      NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(CustomersCollectionChanged);

    return customers;
}

void CustomersCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
    {
        foreach (object item in e.OldItems)
        {
            CustomerUIObject customerObject = item as CustomerUIObject;

            // use the data access layer to delete the wrapped data object
            dataAccessLayer.DeleteCustomer(customerObject.GetDataObject());
        }
    }
}
```

When a user deletes a row with the DataGrid control, the CollectionChanged event is fired on the bound collection. In the event handler, we invoke the DAL DeleteCustomer method with the wrapped data object passed as the parameter.

Handling delete operations is relatively straightforward, but how about updates or insertions? You might think that the same approach can be used, the NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.Action property does include Add operations; however, this event is not fired when the items within the collection are updated. Furthermore, when a user adds a new item to the DataGrid, the object is initially added to the bound collection in a non-initialized state, so we would only ever see the object with its default property values. What we really need to do is determine when the user finishes editing an item in the grid.
Handling Updates / Inserts

To determine when a user finishes editing a bound item, we need to delve a little deeper into the binding mechanism itself. The DataGrid is able to perform an atomic commit of the row which is currently being edited; this is made possible if the bound items implement the IEditableObject interface which exposes BeginEdit, EndEdit, and CancelEdit methods. Typically, an object implementing this interface would return to its state at the point when the BeginEdit method was called as a response to the CancelEdit method being invoked. However, in this instance, we are not really concerned about being able to cancel edits; all we really need to know is when the user has finished editing a row. This is indicted when the DataGrid invokes EndEdit on our bound item.

In order to notify the CustomerDataObjectProvider that EndEdit has been invoked on one of the objects in the bound collection, the CustomerUIObject implements IEditableObject as follows:

```
public delegate void ItemEndEditEventHandler(IEditableObject sender);

public event ItemEndEditEventHandler ItemEndEdit;

#region IEditableObject Members

public void BeginEdit() {}

public void CancelEdit() {}

public void EndEdit()
{
    if (ItemEndEdit != null)
    {
        ItemEndEdit(this);
    }
}

#endregion
```

When items are added to the CustomerUIObjects collection, this event is handled for all the items in the collection, with the handler simply forwarding the event:

```
public class CustomerUIObjects : ObservableCollection<CustomerDataObject>
{
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, CustomerUIObject item)
    {
        base.InsertItem(index, item);

        // handle any EndEdit events relating to this item
        item.ItemEndEdit += new ItemEndEditEventHandler(ItemEndEditHandler);
    }

    void ItemEndEditHandler(IEditableObject sender)
    {
        // simply forward any EndEdit events
        if (ItemEndEdit != null)
        {
            ItemEndEdit(sender);
        }
    }

    public event ItemEndEditEventHandler ItemEndEdit;
}
```

The CustomerObjectDataProvider can now handle this event to receive the notification of CommitEdit being invoked on any of the bound items. It can then invoke the DAL methods to synchronise the database state:

```
public CustomerUIObjects GetCustomers()
{
    // populate our list of customers from the data access layer
    CustomerUIObjects customers = new CustomerUIObjects();

    List<CustomerDataObject> customerDataObjects = dataAccessLayer.GetCustomers();
    foreach (CustomerDataObject customerDataObject in customerDataObjects)
    {
        // create a business object from each data object
        customers.Add(new CustomerUIObject(customerDataObject));
    }

    customers.ItemEndEdit += new ItemEndEditEventHandler(CustomersItemEndEdit);
    customers.CollectionChanged += new
      NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(CustomersCollectionChanged);

    return customers;
}

void CustomersItemEndEdit(IEditableObject sender)
{
    CustomerUIObject customerObject = sender as CustomerUIObject;

    // use the data access layer to update the wrapped data object
    dataAccessLayer.UpdateCustomer(customerObject.GetDataObject());
}
```

The above code will handle both insert and update operations.

In conclusion, this method adapts the data items and collection provided by the DAL into UI items and collections which are more appropriate for data binding within the WPF Framework. All database synchronisation logic is performed by handling event from this bound collection; therefore, there is no WPF DataGrid specific code.